# There is subversion manager for ubuntu?

Tags: svn

I try to set up my ovn svn server.

I have install Ubuntu, apache2, mysql, subversion, subversion apache module already.

But subversion configuration is very difficult for me. There is any subversion manager for ubuntu, which I can use through web to configure my subversion server, create new user accounts and repositoryes?

It also would be gread if repositoryes wil be avaliable from web (like google code).

Comment: if you want your repo to be available from web _and_ on your server, you should take a look at git or mercurial instead of svn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[uberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/) gives you a GUI to manage repositories, teams, users and apache settings, and is cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a web-based SVN server management interface, you can look at

- [User-friendly SVN (USVN)](http://usvn.info/en) which is written in PHP
- [sventon](http://www.sventon.org/) if you prefer a  JAVA solution